# How did David Hill know about his accusations against Lewis Strauss?

Tags: oppenheimer

In the movie **Oppenheimer**, we see that the whole case of **Oppenheimer** (played by Cillian Murphy) vs **Lewis Strauss** (Robert Downey) gets the final verdict based on **David Hill's** (Rami Malek) allegations/accusations.

He is just a Met lab technician, so how does he know all the details of Oppenheimer's and Strauss feud or differences? Could it be Strauss's secretary **Senate Aide** (Alden Ehrenreich)who could have shared the details of their grudge with David Hill?

We see it and it could be perceived in the ending scenes that Aide is shocked at the lengths that Strauss had gone to bring Oppenheimer down (Tipping off FBI that Oppenheimer is a Soviet spy, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

David Hill was not just a lab technician. He worked at Met Lab during the war and was part of the team that built the Chicago pile.  He gained his Ph.D from Princeton in 1951 and worked as a theoretical physicist at Los Alamos.

It was in his capacity as the head of the [Federation of American Scientists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation_of_American_Scientists) that he was asked to testify at the hearing, a role for which I am sure he had many conversations about policy, particularly with respect to his scientific interests in Nuclear Physics for which Lewis Strauss was an important and powerful figure.

It seems to be an openly discussed theory among Oppenheimer's friends and family that the moves against him were orchestrated by Strauss. Oppenheimer seems to ignore these theories rather than directly refute them. As a personal observer in that world, it doesn't seem out of place that Hill would have an antagonistic view of Strauss, not requiring Alden Ehrenreich to leak detail.

Comment: Wikipedia's article on David Hill refers to him as the chair of FAS, but I've also seen articles claiming someone else who testified was the chair of FAS, but who *also* testified against Strauss's appointment.  I'm thinking of buying the American Prometheus book, so perhaps I can clarify this later.

Answer (score -1):

The senate aide had nothing to do with it; Hill was slated to speak before Strauss or his counsel even knew who it was.

It was commonly suspected by Oppenheimer’s peers that Strauss was behind it. And actually the original screenplay goes more into Hill’s rationale, which adds statements about the scientific community being disturbed by Strauss’ repeated unwillingness to accept when he was wrong. I think it’s too bad a lot of it got cut because it was powerful and fleshed Hill’s statement out more, although I also think I understand why it was.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).